# How can I handle water softener output without relying on a sump pump?

Tags: water-softener

We bought a house that had a water softener in the basement. It drains into a crock and gets to our septic by a sub pump. In 6 months the pump has failed twice flooding our unfinished basement. I understand the pumps don't handle the salt brine for long. What can I do to get the water out/avoid buying sub pumps every six months/not damage drinking water from our well? Our basement is not a walkout.

Comment: That really depends on what options you have for graywater disposal on your property. Can you simply route the output hose to the landscape or directly to the septic tank?

Comment: i would add some kind of sensor to cut the thing off before it flooded.

Answer (score 1):

Water softeners can drain up and out. The house I currently live in has a softener drain that runs up about 5 feet from the softener and over through the basement to the drain. So, you could drain it outside fairly easily.

I have never had a problem with it but if you are concerned about drain back you can put a check valve in the drain tube at the beginning next to the softener. Mine doesn't have any and it works fine.

Good luck!